# How do I fix font-stretch property to start working

Tags: css, fonts

font-stretch property doesn't work at all. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>font-stretch</title>
  <style>
   p {
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
   <span style="font-stretch: ultra-condensed">P</span>
   <span style="font-stretch: extra-condensed">P</span>
   <span style="font-stretch: condensed">P</span>
   <span style="font-stretch: semi-condensed">P</span>
   <span style="font-stretch: normal">P</span>
   <span style="font-stretch: semi-expanded">P</span>
   <span style="font-stretch: expanded">P</span>
   <span style="font-stretch: extra-expanded">P</span>
   <span style="font-stretch: ultra-expanded">P</span>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've tried many other fonts and problem still exists. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR: the browser doesn't care about the intrinsic design of a font file

**Adjust `@font-face` rules**

Although a browser  parses font files and can read "intrinsic" style data from its data records it won't automatically map

- styles (italic, regular)
- weights (light, regular, bold etc.)
- font-stretch (condensed, normal, wide etc.)

So you need to specify all these font-family variants via `@font-face` rules

```
/* Myriad Pro - width: condensed - weight: 200/light - style:regular */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: light;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  src: url(MyriadProCondensedLight.woff');
}

/* Myriad Pro - width: condensed - weight: 700/bold- style:italic*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-stretch: 200%;
  src: url(MyriadProExtendedBold.woff');
}
```

Basically you can map any font file to any weight,style or width – and also to any font-family name.
Since the keyword values (e.g thin, condensed, wide etc.) are not self-explanatory I highly recommend to prefer numeric values to organize different weights or widths.

**Google font's UI is currently still preferring a static/single-weight css output.**

But you can manually force the API to output variable font `@font-face` rules:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wdth,wght@50..200,200..900
```

It's important to use **'..' as a range delimiter** – otherwise you'll get a css containing several static `woff2` file urls.

Besides, google's API uses some **user agent detection (a.k.a browser sniffing)** to provide backwards compatibility (for browsers that don't support variable fonts).
This makes perfect sense ... unfortunately, this doesn't work very well: some Browsers like Opera (flawlessly supporting VF) will also receive static fonts.
(This might also apply to other chromium/blink based browsers)

As a workaround I recommend, to open the above css URL in firefox. The result should look something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200 900;
  font-stretch: 50% 200%;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inconsolata/v31/QldKNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKGlZ5qg.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Notice the `font-weight` and `font-stretch` property values containing 2
values for a range of weights/widths. This is a good indicator, you've retrieved the correct (variable) rules.

#### Example: Inconsolata variable

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Inconsolata";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200 900;
  font-stretch: 50% 200%;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inconsolata/v31/QldKNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKGlZ5qg.woff2) format("woff2");
}

body {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: red;
}

p {
  font-family: Inconsolata;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.customMap {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Inconsolata2";
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v25/ieVl2ZhZI2eCN5jzbjEETS9weq8-19K7DQ.woff2) format("woff2");
  font-stretch: 50%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Inconsolata2";
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TLBCc6CsQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  font-stretch: 200%;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.customMap {
  font-family: "Inconsolata2";
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:12px">Font-stretch: <input type="range" id="fontStretch" value="50" min="50" max="200" step="5"></p>
<p style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:12px">Font-weight: <input type="range" id="fontWeight" value="200" min="200" max="900" step="10"></p>
<p id="variableTest" style="font-stretch:50%" class="inconsolata variableTest">Hamburgefons</p>

<h2>Variable fonts Example</h2>

<p>
  <span style="font-stretch: ultra-condensed">P</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: extra-condensed">P</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: condensed">P</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: semi-condensed">P</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: normal">P</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: semi-expanded">P</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: expanded">P</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: extra-expanded">P</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: ultra-expanded">P</span>
</p>

<h2>Static fonts Example (custom fonts to widths mapping)</h2>
<p class="customMap">
  <span style="font-stretch: 50%">g</span>
  <span style="font-stretch: 200%">g</span>
</p>


<script>
  fontStretch.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    variableTest.style.fontStretch = e.currentTarget.value + '%';
  });

  fontWeight.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    variableTest.style.fontWeight = e.currentTarget.value;
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `font-stretch` to select a condensed or expanded face from such fonts. If the font you are using does not offer condensed or expanded faces, this property has no effect.

Comment: I did. I tried Inconsolata and Anek Malayalam
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch#font_face_selection

None of them works correctly

Answer (score 0):

If using a variable font you can set the width variation in css. Widths are from 0-9. Here is the [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-variable-fonts) that guided me.

`font-variation-settings: "wdth" 4;`